# Can we Pass username/pass instead of SessionID in Magento SOAP

Tags: web-services, magento, soap

I dont want to pass the session Id every time to get or update the information using SOAP. Because for that I would have to run a separate request every time to get the session ID. Isn't it possible to provide username/pass everytime before running a SOAP or just once per session??

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Yep this is doable, but it will be some work to do:

1. You should create an custom `Server Handler` by overriding the default one.

   - Create a `Handler.php` file in -`magentopath/app/code/local/Company/Api/Model/Server/Handler.php`
   - Override the `call` method.

     ```
     class Company_Api_Model_Server_Handler
           extends Mage_Api_Model_Server_Handler
     {
          public function call($sessionId, $apiPath, $args = array())
          {
              $sessionId = $this->login($args['username'], $args['password']);
              parent::call($sessionId, $apiPath, $args);
          }
     }
     ```

In this way you cand send null for `$sessionId`, and make an login with the needed credential on the server side.

*I do not suggest this approach at all, but as a workaround it could work.*